# Calculate Day Change in Millis

Tags: java, android

These two lines calculate the number of days since 1970. When I set the time of my phone to 23:55, these two lines should return different values, because 23:55 + 10 minutes is a new day. But somehow both lines return the same value.

```
Log.d("Main", "today " + (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) ) );
Log.d("Main", "tomorrow " + (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)) / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) ) );
```

Log Messages:

```
12-09  17109-17109/com.example..myapplication D/Main: 
today 17874        // 23:55
tomorrow 17874     // 00:05 this line should be 17875, because it's a new day
```

Comment: Use joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9 library for this its very simple to use and play this library

Comment: What time zone? Do you mean the beginning of 1970 in UTC? And do you mean 23:55 in New York, London, Paris, or Munich?

Comment: Do you define “days” as chunks of 24-hours or do you mean days as in dates on the calendar?

Comment: days as in dates on the calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> these two lines should return different values

they would if you did not apply to them integer division.

> because 23:55 + 10 minutes is a new day

yes but since 1970 it is only 10 more minutes.  
Check this code that allows more accurate division than integer division:

```
System.out.println("today " +
        (System.currentTimeMillis() * 1.0 / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
System.out.println("tomorrow " +
        ((System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10)) * 1.0 / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
```

will print:

```
today 17872.55873355324
tomorrow 17872.565677997685
```

Your code truncates the decimal digits and you think that both lines return the same result. 
Of course if instead of adding 10 mins, you add 1 day the result in your code will be correct:

```
System.out.println("today " +
        (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
System.out.println("tomorrow " +
        (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)) / TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)));
```

will print:

```
today 17872
tomorrow 17873
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java Date/Time API correctly, I would go for

```
public long getDaysFromEpoch(Instant moment){
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
             Instant.EPOCH, 
             moment
         );
}
```

Using an instant, you can get an instant from an amount of millisecond :

```
System.out.println(getDaysFromEpoch(Instant.now()));     //17872
System.out.println(getDaysFromEpoch(Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS))); //17873
System.out.println(getDaysFromEpoch(Instant.ofEpochMilli(100_000_000_000L))); //1157
```

Comment: I think Java Date/Time is not available with api 19

Comment: @JanMeyer At first, I wrote about that in my answer but removed it since "recent" android version are in Java 8 and since you didn't mention the version I hope you were using something recent. But this is indeed a problem which should be solved including the ThreeTen-BackPort (never tried on Android....)

Answer (score 0):

Use joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9 library for this its very simple to use and play this library

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).